# this is my Code for MVVM. Is it correct?

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
                DataContext = new Page2ViewModel(this);
            };
    }
```

I Think:

We know MVVM get QueryString is so difficult. so, if i get PhoneApplicationPage refern,i can get NavigationContext and NavigationService. by this way, i can get QueryString by NavigationContext.i can Navigation by NavigationService. But, i don't know this way is MVVM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not 100% MVVM. Your application doesn't have to 100% MVVM. Your ViewModel should NOT talk directly to the view. You can have your ViewModel send events to your view if you need to.

Also you don't need to set the DataContext in the Loaded event.

```
private Page2ViewModel _Page2ViewModel;
public Page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Page2ViewModel = new Page2ViewModel();
    DataContext = Page2ViewModel;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string key = string.Empty;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("key"))
        string key = NavigationContext.QueryString["key"];

    _Page2ViewModel.UpdateKey(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Caliburn Micro.  The navigation service will parse out the values for you and if a property exists on the destination viewmodel it will populate them.

```
public class MainPageViewModel {  
    readonly INavigationService navigationService;  

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) {  
        this.navigationService = navigationService;  
    }  

    public void GotoPageTwo() {  
        navigationService.UriFor<PivotPageViewModel>()  
            .WithParam(x => x.NumberOfTabs, 5)  
            .Navigate();  
    }  
}
```